# Regex: Ignore certain words in statement

Tags: regex

I want to check if certain sentence fits regex statement however I want to ignore some of the previously given word.

Regex statement to improve = AB(\s)CD(\s)EF
ignore words = XX, YY

```
Examples:
AB XX CD YY EF -> should match 
AB YY CD XX EF -> should match 

AB YY CD EF -> should match 
AB CD YY EF -> should match 
AB XX CD EF -> should match 
AB CD XX EF -> should match 

ABYY CD EF -> should NOT match 
AB CD XXEF -> should NOT match
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean "optionally match" the `XX` and `YY`? Like `AB(?:\s(XX|YY))?\sCD(?:\s(XX|YY))?\sEF`? See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GWuZsm/1).

Comment: Actually your answer worked for me =) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
AB(?:\s(XX|YY))?\sCD(?:\s(XX|YY))?\sEF
```

It matches:

- `AB` - `AB`
- `(?:\s(XX|YY))?` - an optional occurrence of a whitespace and then `XX` or `YY`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `CD` - a `CD` string
- `(?:\s(XX|YY))?` - an optional occurrence of a whitespace followed with `XX` or `YY`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `EF` - an `EF` string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/GWuZsm/1).

Answer (score 1):

Making the assumptions that you won't allow neither `AB XX YY CD EF` nor `AB XX CD XX EF`, I came up with:

```
^AB(\s(XX|YY))?\sCD(?!\1)(?1)?\sEF$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UbPhxO/7).

Comment: It looks like my solution worked for OP, so your assumptions do not seem valid for the current scenario.

Comment: I see, I'll delete my suggestion in due time =) @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

You can test for a separator between your expected tokens, where the separator is a space followed by optional XX or YY:

```js
let tests = [
  'AB XX CD YY EF',
  'AB YY CD XX EF',
  'AB YY CD EF',
  'AB CD YY EF',
  'AB XX CD EF',
  'AB CD XX EF',
  'ABYY CD EF',
  'AB CD XXEF'
];
let regex = /^AB(\s((XX|YY)\s)?)CD(\s((XX|YY)\s)?)EF/;
tests.forEach((text) => {
  console.log(text + ' ==> ' + regex.test(text));
});
```

Output:

```
AB XX CD YY EF ==> true
AB YY CD XX EF ==> true
AB YY CD EF ==> true
AB CD YY EF ==> true
AB XX CD EF ==> true
AB CD XX EF ==> true
ABYY CD EF ==> false
AB CD XXEF ==> false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^AB` - expect `AB` at the beginning
- `\s` - followed by whitespace
- `((XX|YY)\s)?` - followed by (`XX` or `YY`) and a whitespace; the `(...)?` makes this sequence optional (0 or 1 occurrences)
- `CD` - followed by `CD`
- `(\s((XX|YY)\s)?)` - followed by same whitespace and optional (`XX` or `YY`) as before
- `EF` - followed by `EF`